# Disable particular warning when /W4 enabled without creating D9025

Tags: qt, visual-c++

How to exclude particular warning for MSVC compiler having /W4 and don't get D9025 warning.
Example:

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS  += -W4
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS  += -wd4127

Generates `warning D9025 : overriding '/W4' with '/W3'`.

Comment: Maybe `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS -= -W3`?

Comment: No.  'QMAKE_CXXFLAGS -= -W3' doesn't solve it.